# Entity Relationship Model - double one to many

Tags: database-design, erd

## ERD

[image: erd]

A customer submits **one or many**  leads.
A lead belongs **to one** customer.
A lead **is a** request or an inquiry.
A lead belongs **to one** manufacturer.
A manufacturer has **one or many** leads.

---

### Tables

Only focusing on manufacturer and lead I set up the tables like below.

```
manufacturer            lead
--------------          ---------------
MId                     LId
name                    MId
description             date
...                     ...
```

Adding customer table I add CustomerId to lead table.

```
manufacturer            lead                customer
--------------          ---------------     ---------------
MId                     LId                 CId
name                    MId                 phone
description             CId                 ...
...                     date   
                        ...
```

---

### Issue:

With all three entity types, is there a benefit to have an additional linking table instead adding ManufacturerId(`MId`) and CustomerId(`CId`)  as column to Lead table? Does this offend any best practice? Or should I even include two separated linking tables? Thank you for Explanation and 'further reading links'.

Answer (score 3):

Your `LEAD` table is an intersection between `MANUFACTURER` and `CUSTOMER`.  That is a perfectly legitimate design.  Intersection tables don't have to be *pure* intersections.  They can have other attributes in their own right (such as your `date` or `type`).

Answer (score 1):

If you construct a "pure" intersection table with just MId and CId columns, what would its primary key be?  Even the composite of those two would not be sufficient because, by your stated rule, a customer can submit mulitple leads of different types at different times to the same manufacturer.  So the natural key to the interaction between `Customer` and `Manufacturer` is MId, CId, Type and Date(time), which is what you've documented for `Lead`.  Since it cannot have a unique primary key the "pure" intersection table cannot be a normalised relation.  The stated design is perfectly fine and accords with good practice.

Lead.LId is a surrogate key in this context.  If no other table has a foreign key pointing back to `Lead` I would be inclined to dispense with LId, but the difference is marginal.

Comment: What normal form does LEAD violate?

Comment: @WalterMitty; not `lead` per se more the putative pure intersection table.  It cannot have a candidate key since no combination of fields can be unique.  No key, no normalisation.

Answer (score 0):

In the Entity-Relationship data model, LEAD could be viewed as a many-to-many relationship between MANUFACTURER and CUSTOMER, a pair of entities.  Relationships can have attributes of their own, as LEAD explicitly does.  ER diagrams are sometimes used to depict ER models, but sometimes they are used to depict relational or SQL models.

In a relational model, MANUFACTURER, CUSTOMER, and LEAD are all relations.

In an SQL model, all three are tables.  That seems to be the way you are using ER diagrams.  In both the relational model and the SQL model, an *intersection* or *junction* table is used to implement a many-to-many relationship.

Nothing wrong with your design.  It is probably satisfactory and may well be optimal.  That depends on what you are doing.

update: if CID and LID do not uniquely identify a LEAD, then the above answer needs to be completely revised.  In that case, LEAD is indeed a third entity, not a relationship.